# Add elements of a list together python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, math, numbers

I have this list

```
r1 = 2
r2 = 4
r3 = 5
r4 = 9 
lst = [r1, r2, r3, r4]
```

I want to create a new list which looks like this:

```
new_lst = [r1, r1+r2, r1+r2+r3, r1+r2+r3+r4]
```

Except in the new_lst r1 is named "x1", r1+r2 named "x2 etc.

I'm currently doing this using:

```
new_lst = []
new_lst.append(sum(lst[0:1]))
new_lst.append(sum(lst[0:2]))
new_lst.append(sum(lst[0:3]))    
new_lst.append(sum(lst[0:4]))
```

And then refer to this list by saying if "n" is between 0 and x1, x1 and x1+x2 etc; print y. i.e.

```
 if n >=0 and n <= new_lst[0]:
      print(y)
 elif n >=new_lst[0] and n <= new_lst[1]:
      print(z)
```

Comment: do you have your own code attempt at doing this?

Comment: I do, i'll add it to the post

Comment: Don't use such unrelated variables only 'structured' by their similar names. Use lists.

Answer (score 1):

The code below does create the new_list.

```
lst = [2,4,5,9]
new_lst = [sum(lst[0:i+1]) for i,v in enumerate(lst)]
```

Comment: Where did you define x1, x2, x3, and x4?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the cumulative sum function in numpy?

```
import numpy as np

print(np.array([2,4,5,9]).cumsum())
```

Comment: Where did you define x1, x2, x3, and x4?

Comment: The OP talks about xn's but then uses new_lst[0], new_lst[1], etc. I thought they were more a description, not that the OP wanted arbitrary execution.

Comment: BTW, you can also do, locals()['x'] = 7, to create a variable instead of exec().

Answer (score 0):

This might seem a bit unpractical, but it does include defining the x1, x2, x3 and x4 you mentioned in your post:

```
r1 = 2
r2 = 4
r3 = 5
r4 = 9 
lst = [r1, r2, r3, r4]
new_lst = []
s = ''
for n in range(1,len(lst)+1):
    s += f'+r{n}'
    exec(f'x{n}='+s)
    new_lst.append(eval(f'x{n}'))

print(new_lst)
```

This is not recommended though, because it uses exec, which is considered a bad practice because it's generally abused to do a task where it isn't needed, leading to potential security issues and generally bad programming.

If possible, just define the variables manually, or, there's also a way to let python write them all into a separate file so you can copy and paste it into your main script.

Answer (score 0):

As best as I can understand your question, I believe the following does what you describe.  It creates x1 through x4 via simple list assignment:

```
r1 = 2
r2 = 4
r3 = 5
r4 = 9

array = [r1, r2, r3, r4]

x1, x2, x3, x4 = [sum(array[0:n + 1]) for n in range(len(array))]

if 0 <= n <= x1:
    print(y)
elif x1 <= n <= x2:
    print(z)
```

The fact that you need to do this at all suggests to me you've gone down a wrong path somewhere.  Perhaps you're using individual variables where a `dict` would serve you better.